# OneNote Desktop App crashing always on startup

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-onenote

In our corporate environment we are deploying Office 365 64bit including OneNote. Since approximately 2 weeks several users complained that they're unable to start the OneNote desktop app. During startup the following error message occurs:

[image]

Neither of the proposed actions is solving the problem.

In the Windows Event Viewer we can find the following error:

[image]

I tried the following steps up to now, without any success:

- Reinstalling Office 365
- Starting OneNote in safeboot mode
- Office repair
- Deleted cache under "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\OneNote"
- Signed out in all office application

The affected devices have Windows versions ranging from 1709 up to latest 20H2. The device models are all different, mainly HP Elitebooks. There were no updates in our environment which could have affected office. There are aswell a lot of users who still can use OneNote without any issues, even on same devices with the same software and hardware configuration.

A workaround is to use the Windows 10 App or the Web-App but this are ways which we want to avoid.

How could we solve this problem with our OneNote Desktop App?

Comment: "I tried ... Reinstalling Office 365 ... and other things"  One Note Desktop 64-bit should work fine without crashing and does on my machines. I would be inclined to think it might be a damaged Notebook.

Comment: It is already OneNote 64-bit and there is no damage to this notebook.

Comment: Look for other incompatible software on the machine. Maybe do a fresh install of Windows on one problem computer and build up the computer in chunks (Windows and office first) to see if you can determine the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We started having this exact same issue in our environment about two weeks ago; today, a fourth user has contacted our help desk with this problem.

We thought that MS Support provided us with a viable solution (completely nuking Office installations/service/regkeys), but applying the provided fix only worked on the first end-user experiencing this issue.

Here's to hoping a fix will come soon. We're asking our end-users to use OneNote from a browser, in the meantime, but this is not a solution for users with locally-saved notebooks.

Edit 2/24/21:

Hello,
I have discovered what was causing OneNote to crash at startup in our environment, and I hope this helps anyone that stumbles upon this page.
I can confirm that manually setting the following regkey to "0" allows OneNote to start. This registry value is to force "Open documents from Office Document Cache first", and comes packaged with Microsoft's Office 2016 Administrative Template ADMX files:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\common\internet\disableserverreachability